# onTouchEvent Action_Move choppy interaction

Tags: android, surfaceview, touch-event

I have the following code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            fingerSize = event.getSize();
            fingerPosX = event.getX();
            fingerPosY = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                start = true;
                break;

            }



            }
            return true;
        }
```

I use the three variables fingerSize, fingerPosX and fingerPosY to draw a circle:

```
canvas.drawCircle(fingerPosX, fingerPosY, fingerSize
                    * fingersizeCorrection, paint);
```

So basically the circle follows my finger as i move through the screen with my finger. The problem is that the movement of the circle as it tries to follow my finger is very choppy.

How this be improved to be more fluint?

this all happens in a SurfaceView, i also added a fps limiter like this:

```
int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;
        int SKIP_TICKS = 1000/FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
        long next_game_tick = timer.getElapsedTimeMil();
        int sleep_time = 0;

next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
                sleep_time = (int) (next_game_tick-timer.getElapsedTimeMil());
                if(sleep_time >= 0){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleep_time);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{

                }
```

Comment: Add case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and update the circle params there.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: Where do you call that sleep?

Comment: I already tried MotionEven.ACTION_MOVE, the choppyness was worse, not better. I call the sleep at the end of the gameloop, first i call the method calculatePhysics, then i call the method drawSprites, after that i call the sleep.

Comment: Do you have choppiness without sleep as well?

Comment: Yes i do. But i noticed that it's not always choppy, sometimes when i start the app it works perfect, other times it's choppy.

Comment: it just doesn't sound right to me to sleep inside draw routine.